# CMAKE C Macro not propagating to include directory

Tags: c, cmake, cmakelists-options

I have a Open source C library I want to compile but to set the compiler to recognize OpenMPI is have to set the C macro `PARALLEL` to 1 so that in the header files the:

```
#ifdef PARALLEL
#include <mpi.h>
#endif
```

Will execute. Below is the CMAKE file I'm dealing with where it adds the src directory as a subdirectory and the header file as an include_directory.

Using this sets the C macro `PARELLEL` correctly for everything in the src directory. However, everything in the include directory is left with `PARALLEL` undefined.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(SDFC VERSION 14.4.2 LANGUAGES C)

option(PARALLEL "Using MPI" ON)


set(TOPLEVEL "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
#file(GLOB SOURCE_ALL include/*inc CMakeLists.txt Makefile*)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -fpic -g")
if(${CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID} STREQUAL "GNU")
   set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG} -gdwarf-2")
endif()

set(SDFC_INCLUDE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include" CACHE PATH
    "Path to include files for SDF C library")
set(SDFC_LIB_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/src" CACHE PATH
    "Path to build directory for SDF C library")


include_directories(include)
add_subdirectory(src)

if(PARALLEL)
   find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
   include_directories(${MPI_C_INCLUDE_PATH})
   add_compile_definitions(-DPARALLEL)
   #add_compile_definitions(-DPARALLEL)
   include(CMake/CheckMPIVersion.cmake)
endif()



install(DIRECTORY include DESTINATION . COMPONENT develop PATTERN uthash.h EXCLUDE)
install(FILES src/uthash/include/uthash.h DESTINATION include COMPONENT develop)
```

I use:

```
cmake .
make
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you add the subdir first and then set add the definition, the definition won't apply to the sbdirectory. Also you just need to use `add_compile_definitions(PARALLEL)` Also you probably don't want to apply the `-g` option for release builds; leave this setting up to cmake; It should automatically be added, if you set up the project in debug configuration. Furthermore in general you should use existing cmake features functionality instead of applying options yourself to make the use of different compilers easier: get rid of `-fpic` and use `set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE True)`

Comment: @fabian thanks. I moved the add_compile_definitions(PARALLEL) to the begining of the cmakelist file but it still did not work. The header files under the include_subdirectories(include) are still not seeing the defined PARALLEL

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that just because a static library is compiled and built using CMAKE which sets the preprocessor macros for header file (say `library.h`):

```
#ifdef PARALLEL
#include <mpi.h>
#endif
```

Doesn't mean you can use the static library and header file in your new code without defining the preprocessor macro.

So after making this static library with:

```
cmake .
make
```

I got a `library.a` file

In order to link it to my new code, say `main.c` that uses `#include "library.h"`, I had to not only include the library and header file directory in the command line but also had to define the preprocessor macro `PARALLEL` as follows:

```
gcc -DPARALLEL=1 -L/Path_To_Library_Directory -I/Path_To_Include_Directory main.c -o main -llibrary
```

Comment: If you're using the target with cmake, `target_compile_definitions(library PUBLIC PARALLEL)` makes sure every linking target will define the symbol. In case you want extern code to use the lib built in cmake, I recommend generating a header file `#ifndef LIBRARY_CONFIG #define LIBRARY_CONFIG #define PARALLEL=1 #endif` and include it in the relevant public headers of library; cmake provides functionality for generating a a file from a pattern file via `configure_file` command. This would make the lib easier to use.

Comment: @fabian, that makes sense. thanks again